# When using Bluemix App Id serivices, what if the user does not have google Id or Facebook Id

Tags: facebook, ibm-cloud, app-id

I am proposing a solution to use App Id service in Bluemix for my mobile application (both Android and iOS). I read the document in Bluemix, and got a good understanding how it works. But I still have a question I cannot find an answer yet.
The question is: how to handle the situation when the user does not have either google id or facebook id?

Comment: Hi @Rabbit, I updated the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

Yes, this feature is now supported in App ID:

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/11/new-app-id-let-users-sign-sign-apps-email-password/